# I am trying to create a Collatz sequence with while loop in R. What am i doing wrong in this while loop here?

Tags: r, while-loop, collatz

I am trying to create a Collatz sequence with while loop in R.

```
vector <-  NULL
n <- 10
while (n != 1) {
  if (n %% 2 == 0) {
    n <- n / 2
  } else {
    n <- (n * 3) + 1
  }
  vector <- c(vector, cbind(n))
  print(vector)
}
```

After running the code, I got:

```
[1] 5
[1]  5 16
[1]  5 16  8
[1]  5 16  8  4
[1]  5 16  8  4  2
[1]  5 16  8  4  2  1
```

How do I do it such that it only shows the last row? What went wrong in my code?
Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Perhaps you need to `print(n)`

Comment: or use `print(vector)` outside the loop

Comment: You don't need `cbind` - just `vector <- c(vector, n)` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to deal with `print(vector)`

- add `if` condition before `print(vector)`, i.e.,

```
vector <-  NULL
n <- 10
while (n != 1) {
  if (n %% 2 == 0) {
    n <- n / 2
  } else {
    n <- (n * 3) + 1
  }
  vector <- c(vector, cbind(n))
  if (n==1)  print(vector)
}
```

- move it outside `while` loop, i.e.,

```
vector <-  NULL
n <- 10
while (n != 1) {
  if (n %% 2 == 0) {
    n <- n / 2
  } else {
    n <- (n * 3) + 1
  }
  vector <- c(vector, cbind(n))
}
print(vector)
```